# How to create a single column DataFrame in sparkR?

Tags: r, sparkr

How can I create a single-column DataFrame in SparkR? Suppose we have the following column `x`, how can I create a `DataFrame` out of it?

```
## Assumes a running sparkR shell
data("ChickWeight")
cwDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, ChickWeight)
x <- cwDF$Chick
```

There seems to be a generic `toDF` function but no methods. Any idea how to change x into a single-column `DataFrame` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use select function,

```
x <- select(cwDF,"Chick")
```

instead of `x <- cwDF$Chick` which is a r code.
We get the result as in image below in sparkR shell,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use `select` function:

```
chicks <- select(cwDF, cwDF$Chick)
head(chicks)

##   Chick
## 1     1
## 2     1
## 3     1
## 4     1
## 5     1
## 6     1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x.df <- data.frame(Chick = x)
```